# FFMPEG command works in PowerShell but not in a batch file

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, variables

Simply trying to extract frames from a video file using ffmpeg in a .bat file and it doesn't work:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -qscale:v 1 -qmin 1 -qmax 1 -vsync 0 tmp_frames/frame%08d.jpg
```

The error message:

> Unable to find a suitable output format for '.\tmp_frames\frameC:\Test'
> .\tmp_frames\frameC:\Test: Invalid argument

This command works fine in PowerShell by itself, but running it as a batch file yields the above error.

Any ideas on how to fix this in the batch file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the `.bat` file, you must use the escape code for `%`, which is `%%`

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -qscale:v 1 -qmin 1 -qmax 1 -vsync 0 tmp_frames/frame%%08d.jpg
```

Answer (score 2):

`...frame%08d.jpg` : `%0` will be replaced by the current batchfile name, hence
'.\tmp_frames\frame**C:\Test**'

Comment: Is there an alternative I can use that won't do that?

Comment: Possibly, but I've no idea what you want in place of `%08...` What is it intended to do?

Comment: It's an ffmpeg command that basically turns the current iterating frame in the video file into a PNG file.